# Remove bracket from a particular string

Tags: awk, sed

If some text is like

```
cell (ABC)
(A1)
(A2)
function (A1.A2)
```

I want output as

```
cell ABC
A1
A2
function (A1.A2)
```

I want to remove bracket from each line of file except the present in function line.
Using code

```
sed 's/[()]//g' file
```

Removes bracket from each line. How can I modify the above code to get desired output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a jump out condition to your sed command:

```
sed '/^function /b;s/[()]//g' file
```

Or, condition the substitute on not matching a function:

```
sed '/^function /!s/[()]//g' file
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your answer before posting mine. ++

Answer (score 6):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '!/function/{gsub(/[()]/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                ##Starting awk program from here.
!/function/{         ##Checking condition if line does not have function in it then do following.
  gsub(/[()]/,"")    ##Globally substituting ( OR ) with null in current line.
}
1                    ##1 will print current line.
' Input_file         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: `gsub(/[()]/,"")` might be shorter